# Adding class to ArrayList in constructor in Java

Tags: java

I've got a abstract class setup like this:

```
public class Items extends ExternalClass
{
    List<?> enabled = new ArrayList<?>();
    public Items(String name){
        super(name)
    }

    public loadItems(){
         new MyItems("myitems");
         new YourItems("youritems");  
    }
}

public class MyItems extends Items
{
    public MyItems(String name){
          super(name)
    }

    public String getUsage(){
    return "My items";
    }
}

public class YourItems extends Items
{
    public YourItems(String name){
          super(name)
    }

    public String getUsage(){
    return "Your items";
    }
}
```

I don't know how to add MyItems and YourItems to the List enabled. I want to use getUsage() outside of the Items Class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Implement

```
public String getUsage()
```

for your `Items` `class`, use `ArrayList<Items>` instead of `ArrayList<?>` and then you will be able to call the elements' `getUsage` because `MyItems` and `YourItems` `extends` the `class` of `Items`.

Answer (score 1):

First, you can't instantiate an instance of a generic class with a wildcard.  The compiler will give you an error for `new ArrayList<?>();`.  You must supply a type parameter.  However, it seems you can use the diamond operator `new ArrayList<>();`.

Next, you can't call `add` with anything except `null` on a collection with an unbounded wildcard.  The type parameter doesn't indicate what can be added, it indicates what it already contains.  It could be a `List` of anything - `List<Object>`, `List<? extends Number>`, or even `List<Foo>`.  Because you've indicated that the type parameter is unknown, and because the compiler must preserve type safety, the compiler must disallow this call.  Only `null` can be passed here; `null` can be of any type.

If you must add any type of object, use a `Object` as the type parameter.

Comment: I know, it's just an example. It's just how to add MyItems to ArrayList